# How to sort based on date and time from a sql query into a GridView

Tags: c#, sql

Sorting the function like this on page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["sortOrder"] = "Desc";
    ViewState["sortExp"] = "Completed Date";
    PD("Completed Date", "Desc", true);
}

public void PD(string sortExp, string sortDir, bool blOnLoad)
{
    string qry = @"Select [status] 'Status', [Completed Date] 'Completed Date' FROM [mydb1].[dbo].[table1]";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(gloString))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);

            myDataSet = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(myDataSet);

            myDataView = new DataView();
            myDataView = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;

            if (sortExp != string.Empty)
            {
                myDataView.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", sortExp, sortDir);
            }

            yourTasksGV.DataSource = myDataView;
            yourTasksGV.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
protected void yourTasksGV_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["sortExp"] = e.SortExpression;
    PD(e.SortExpression, sortOrder, false);
}
public string sortOrder
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString() == "Desc")
        {
            ViewState["sortOrder"] = "Asc";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewState["sortOrder"] = "Desc";
        }

        return ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["sortOrder"] = value;
    }
}
```

The `[Completed Date]` column is of `datetime` type.

```
RTRIM(Att12) 'Completed Date' = "May 20 2015  2:44PM"
RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Att12, 101)) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, RTRIM(Att12), 100), 7) 'Completed Date' = "05/20/2015  2:44PM" //this is being used for the bottom result.
```

After the above code runs, this is the result:

```
Completed Date
06/11/2015 11:39AM                                                      
06/11/2015  3:38PM                                                      
06/11/2015  1:12PM                                                      
06/11/2015  1:11PM                                                      
06/11/2015  1:06PM                                                      
06/11/2015  1:05PM                                                      
06/11/2015  1:04PM                                                      
06/11/2015  1:03PM                                                      
06/10/2015  9:35AM                                                      
06/09/2015 12:29PM                                                      
06/09/2015 12:24PM                                                      
06/09/2015 12:20PM                                                      
06/09/2015  9:40AM                                                      
06/09/2015  9:16AM                                                      
06/09/2015  9:11AM                                                      
06/05/2015 10:33AM                                                      
06/05/2015  8:35AM
```

As you can see the `11:39AM` is always stuck at the top.

How can I modify the script to ensure is it correctly sorted.

Comment: Why can't you include the sorting in your SQL query itself as `order by`? Again you are calling `PD(....)` whereas the method name is `PullData(...)` is that a typo?

Comment: Because I am using the `Sorting` function in C# to allow sorting. I will update my question.

Comment: Check your Dataview and make sure is type DateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with square bracket around the sort expression:

```
ViewState["sortOrder"] = "DESC";
ViewState["sortExp"] = "[Completed Date]";
```

Also, your [Completed Date] field should be of DateTime datatype. Don't convert it to string to get the required format. You can use string formatting to get any desired formatting for output. So your select statement should return `Att12` datetime field:

```
Select [status] 'Status', [Att12] 'Completed Date' FROM [mydb1].[dbo].[table1]"
```

Then for display you can use string formatting:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt")
```

Or you can format the column in your grid to display the date time that format. For formatting reference you can checkout [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I have the same line in my code with more detail. Is that not right?

Comment: I've udpated my reply. Can you try again placing the sort expression in the square bracket?

Comment: The same result. The `11` is going before `1`

Comment: Does [Completed Date] column in the `DataTable` have `DateTime` data type?

Comment: When debugging and I view it, how do I check it?

Comment: While debugging you can hover over the datatable object and navigate to columns to find out its datatype. Or you can use quick watch/watch window to find it out.

Comment: I only have a DataView, I will convert it into a DataTable and check.

Comment: It is coming as `System.String`

Comment: That is why your result is not as you expected. Convert [Completed Date] field to datetime type and then your sort will work.

Comment: This is the query: `SELECT
 RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CT.A23, 101)) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, RTRIM(CT.A23), 100), 7) 'Completed Date'
FROM [mydb1].[dbo].[table1] CT ` I am concatenating the same field to get the date and time in the proper format and that is why they are string. How can I convert it back into DateTime?

Comment: What datatype is CT.A23 field?

Comment: It originall is datetime type but I would like it this format: `05/20/2015  2:44PM` But by default the second comes with it.

Comment: It is inside a GridView so I will have to use a templatefield than to use `Eval` statement

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting brackets around `Completed Date`?

`ViewState["sortExp"] = "[Completed Date]";`

Comment: still the same result. The `11` is taking precedence over `1`.